# Ninject on asp.net Session state

Tags: asp.net, session, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I'm working with Ninject on a web application, using the BasePage and BaseMaster from the frameworks's integrations.  What I would like to do is have an object injected and have a new instance created on each session.  I've looked at the OnePerRequest behavior and it's close, but not quite.
What I'm doing is performing a lot of calculations, and those
variables are held in objects that are injected into the page.  I need
those objects to stay around for postbacks, but I want a new instance
of the objects each time the user "Visits" the site.  My initial
thinking was to use the Asp.net Session object in some way to store
the values between postbacks,  This is the way I would do it before Ninject (just store the objects in session.  but I'd like to use Ninject in the correct way if I can.
I'm open to other suggestions.  I thought about using the Singleton, but each user is going to need their own copy of the object, otherwise they'll step on each others
calculations.

I hope that is clear, and I would appreciate any advice on either
using an existing behavior or creating my own.  Perhaps using the application cache or the  builtin ASP.NET caching could work.

Thank you

Josh

Comment: I would also like an answer to this question!

Comment: What version of Ninject are you planning on using?